# Where to put my global variables in Microsoft Visual Studio Form?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Where do I put my variables and functions in this? I'm trying out Microsoft Visual Studio because I'm creating a UI for practice. However, I don't know where to put my variables so that both Forms have "scope" over it (so both Forms can see and interact with the variable).

I have two Forms that I made:

Form #1: Main Home Form that contains a drop-down menu that allows a user to log in and also has features that pop up afterwards to show their game statistics.

Form #2:  The log-in Form that, after a user clicks on the log in menu, shows up to allow the user to type in their Username and Password. Once they click the log-in button, it'll authenticate if both the Username and Password match what's on the database.

What I'm trying to do is to have both forms able to see the same variables. If I instantiate a variable such as `String username = "";` on one Form, my other Form can't see it. Is there a way to instantiate a global variable so all Forms can 'see' it?

Sorry if anything seems unclear.

Comment: pass a reference in constructor to share the data.

Comment: @Jarod42, could you give me an example? Just to clarify, there are two .cpp and two .h files.

Comment: Create a class containing the data that you want to share, and give a reference to that class to both forms. Note about the [tag:visual-studio] tag: if you read the description, it says *"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*